# Routing issue in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

For user profile I make an action in home controller and I want that when user click on my profile link only shows www.abc.com/profile

For it I do

```
get '/profile' => 'home#profile'
```

But now issue is that there is a need to send user id along with that.If I send it in format then url become

```
www.abc.com/profile.4
```

I want that url remains '/profile' and Id of user also send

Comment: Do you have login functionality already set up?

Comment: please paste your controller here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the url to stay `/profile` then you'll have to rely on your login implementation. I've not used devise myself, but according to the documentation it provides you with a `current_user` method to use in your controllers. So your `HomeController#profile` would look something like this:

```
def profile
  @user = current_user
  render :profile
end
```

That way you don't need the client to send the id to you, because (as I understand it) this should be the profile page of the logged in user, which you should already have information about through devise.

Otherwise you need to allow the id to come through the path by defining the route like so:

```
get '/profile/:id' => "home#profile"
```

Comment: I do by this way get '/profile/:id' => "home#profile" but when I do rake routes No prefix come for this. Which prefix I use?

Comment: you can stipulate a prefix with 'as' like so: get "/profile/:id" => "home#profile", as: "profile"

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're setting it as a [*member*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) route (it expects to pass the `id` for the controller). You need to replace it with a [*collection*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) route, *if* you're going to nest it:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users ... do
   get :profile, to: "home#profile", on: :collection, as: :profile #-> url.com/users/profile
end
```

You'd then be able to access the profile as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", users_profiles_path, if user_signed_in? %>
```

If you wanted to make it so that you could access `profile` without nesting, your route would work:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "profile", to: "home#profile", as: :profile

<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path if user_signed_in? %>
```

---

**Controller**

We have a setup similar to this, let me explain the controller setup...

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def edit
      @user = current_user
   end
   def update
      @user = current_user
      ...
   end
end
```

This gives us the ability to use the following (we also use devise):

```
#config/routes.rb
resource  :profile, path: "profile", controller: :users, path_names: { edit: "" }, only: [:edit, :update]   #-> domain.com/profile
```

Comment: When I do this nothing show related to that in rake routes

Comment: Show routes file and rake routes. I'm not going to do your work for you, make an effort.

Comment: I don't think the `path: "profile"` part is necessary... Is it?

Comment: Not in the bottom example. I should change that actually because I lifted it out of some of our own code

Answer (score 0):

in devise gem they had mentioned current_user model so use

```
current_user.id
```

to find the User id so that in your profile action do like this, and pass the user id of current user so that you can easily fetch his details

Comment: @RichPeck thanks for your reply yes i misunderstood the question.